# Best Cross Platform Networking Framework For iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, networking, cross-platform, network-programming

I am looking to write a client/server application that will run on both iPhone, OS X and Windows. What are the best solutions for networking that will work on all 3 platforms?

I have looked into Qt and it doesn't look like it has support for iPhone. I have also looked at boost, and that looks like it can be compiled for the iPhone. However I was hoping for a somewhat higher level framework like what Qt has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I use AsyncSocket.

OS X/iPhone: http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

Windoze: http://code.google.com/p/dotnetasyncsocket/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the *framework* matters as much as the protocol.  If you go with a standard protocol for communication (most likely some HTTP/REST setup), then there will probably be a library in the native language to communicate via that protocol.